# Search data and Filter by several parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a method that returns a page with pagination.I need to add a function that will return a page with pagination, but it is also possible to sort by two parameters (city and gender). What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please check your question. It is not clear if you want to sort or filter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check for class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable, it can handle pagination and sorting at the same time.
Example of use :

**Controller**

```
 @GetMapping("/users")
 public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getUsers(SearchUserDTO search, Pageable pageable) {
 //Service Implementation
 return new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

**Endpoint**

> http://localhost:8080/api/users?page=0&size=12&sort=att1,attr2,desc

The sorting parameters and the order are sent by the request as request parameters using the sort attribute in the URL. After that Spring will automatically map the sorting attributes with the Pageable object and you can get your sorting information from the Controller by using Pageable.getSort().

Comment: But I need to filter, that is, if a city is selected, then users from this city should be returned, and if it is a gender, then of that gender or both at the same time?

Comment: @Dmytro i don't understand what you mean by filter.
Your first question was about ordering.So if you want to order by the "city" you keep only the attribute "city" in the "sort" parameter and so on.